# How to release a "PopUp" view"?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I have this class that shows a popup.
I do a alloc-init on it and it comes up.

```
DarkVader* darkPopUp = [[DarkVader alloc] init:theButton helpMessage:[theButton.titleLabel.text intValue] isADay:NO offset:0];
```

It shows itself and if the user presses Ok it disappears. When do I release this?

I could do a [self release] in the class when the OK button is pressed. Is this correct?
If I do this the Analyzer says it has a retain count of +1 and gets leaked in the calling function.
If I release it just after the alloc-init the Analyzer says it has a retain count of +0 and i should not release it.

```
    DLog(@"DarkVader retain count: %i", [darkPopUp retainCount]);
```

says it has a retain count of 2. I'm confused.

In short my question is: How do I release an object that gets initialized does some work and ends but no one is there to release it in the calling function.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use

```
[self autorelease];
```

when the view is closing itself. Although if you look at various standard views, then all implement callbacks to a delegate that becomes responsible for closing them; this let's the launching object be responsible for releasing the view as well. You also don't make it clear how your view (or is it a view controller) is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something similar to what existing Cocoa Touch classes does. For example, see how you show an `UIAlertView`:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

It's quite clear that `UIAlertView` does a `[self retain]`, or more likely, gets retained when added as a subview somewhere on the screen somewhere in the `show` method.

There are some Cocoa Touch classes that indeed (just as Paul mentioned) do not support this way of release at once, but instead calls a delegate method and excepts the receiver to release it.

I'd say the answer is, if your `DarkVader` is an `UIView`, you should let the subview-retain take care of the retain count. If it's a `UIViewController` or a custom helper class, you have a few options, the delegate way being a simple and straight forward one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a custom pop-up in the style you described you should probably already be subclassing UIAlertView to begin with. Then you can use it's already implemented retain/release functionality.